# How granular is access control on HDFS for unstructured data?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, acl, bigdata

I am looking for any piece of technical paper explaining how **access control** is conducted on **unstructured data ingested by HDFS**.

1. Can the **granularity level** be smaller than *POSIX-ish* file permissions?
2. Similarly, how would products like ***RecordService*** (from *Cloudera*), which provide an abstraction layer for security on storage components, work on unstructured data?

---

For instance, if I have a very big emails archive file (more than a terabyte), would I be able to specify a more fine-grained ACL than one on the entire file itself? I am thinking about *email headers*, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The granularity supported is to the row and column levels. [See details](http://vision.cloudera.com/introducing-recordservice-the-future-of-security-authorization-in-hadoop/).
2. Presently, for RecordService to work, your data must be organized as Hive Metastore tables. In the future, RecordService may infer structure/schema from the files themselves (but, not the case today).